# Error in UseMethod("read_xml") : no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "list"

Tags: r, text

I have vectors of the some text files. Here how I processed

`text[1] <- read_html("link1")
text[2] <- read_html("link2")
text[3] <- read_html("link3")
.
. until text [100]`

I wanted to create a corpus with following:

`x <- list(text[i])
z <- lapply(x, read_html)`

I got

`Error in UseMethod("read_xml") : no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "list"`

Before that error, it was logical data, I have converted text[i] with following

`text[i] <- as.character (text[i])`

Additionally, I got

`number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement`

I could not figure out what is going on.
Thanks.

Comment: try o remove `[i]` from `x <- list(text[i])`

Comment: still there is same error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

```
x <- rep("https://www.google.com/", 3)
z <- lapply(x, read_html)
```

and it works?

Comment: But I have 100 different html links, how can I apply it with having list of them? Thank you for your time.

Comment: x is a vector of links. Just put them in x

Comment: yes, I think if I would create vector of the links it would work. I have these kind of vectors `text[1] <- read_html("link1")`. Thats why that method does not work.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Why can't you put links in a vector?